# Function pointers passed as template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I was reading through some code and I found a case where a function pointer (the address, not the type) is passed to a template parameter.

```
// connects a free function
registry.on_construct<position>().connect<&my_free_function>();
 
// connects a member function
registry.on_construct<position>().connect<&my_class::member>(instance);
```

I have not seen this before. As I thought only types and integers can be passed to template parameters, and I thought you needed to do something like this:

```
connect<decltype(&my_free_function)>(&my_free_function);
```

It took me ages to realize that this may be a way of statically binding and calling a function pointer? Which I haven't ever seen before. The called code looks something like this:

```
void my_free_function() { std::cout << "free function called\n"; }

template <auto Function>
void templatedFunc()
{
    std::cout << typeid(Function).name();
    // The type of Function according to type_info is void (__cdelc*)(void)
    
    Function(); // This means we call Function function pointer with no dynamic/runtime binding?
    

}

int main()
{

    templatedFunc<&my_free_function>();
}
```

Is this doing what I think it's doing, ie., statically bound call of a function pointer? Does the template parameter need to be auto for this to work? Neither 'typename' nor 'class' nor 'int' works.

Comment: [Template_non-type_arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments).

Comment: `template <void (*Function)()> void templatedFunc();` is also possible, but more limited.

Comment: "As I thought only types and integers can be passed to template parameters" - the "non-type" case doesn't include only integers; the is also the [template-template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this doing what I think it's doing, ie., statically bound call of a function pointer?

Yes, this is doing exactly what you think it's doing. It binds the argument as part of the type itself so that it's not needed to be passed as a runtime argument

> Does the template parameter need to be auto for this to work?

No -- `auto` just makes it more flexible so that it may accept an instance of *any* invokable object -- whether it's a function pointer, a general lambda, or even a functor object.

For function pointers specifically, this could also have been written:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename...Args>
class signal<R(Args...)>
{
    ...
    template <R(*Fn)(Args...)>
    auto connect() -> void;
    ...
};
```

But note, however, that in doing this it forces the *exact* signature -- which is not quite as expressive. For example, you can't do:

```cpp
float add(float, float);

auto sig = signal<double(double,double)>{};

sig.connect<&add>(); // error: float(*)(float, float) cannot be converted to double(*)(double, double) for template param
```

With `auto`, it allows you to *deduce* the argument type -- and can allow a template such as this to support implicit conversions -- which can actually be quite powerful if used correctly. This is kind of like how `std::function` can bind a function with similar but not identical arguments and have it still work -- except this is all done statically rather than dynamically.

---

In case you're curious *why* this pattern is used over a runtime argument, it's because it enables a really simple form of **type-erasure** when building a callback system. Keeping the function statically allows the compiler to inline the code much better than `std::function` can, and it also has a smaller memory footprint.

By using function `template`s, the signature of the *instantiated* function template never changes -- which allows a homogeneous way of storing this for later:

```cpp
template <typename R, typenmae...Args>
class delegate<R(Args...)> {
    ...
    // The function that will expand into the same pointer-type each time
    template <auto Fn>
    static auto invoke_stub(Args...) -> R;

    ...
    // The stub to store
    R(*m_stub)(Args...);
    ...
};
```

For a `delegate<int(int)>`, it doesn't matter if the `invoke_stub` is expanded with a function pointer of type `short(*)(short)`, `int(*)((short)`, etc -- the `decltype(invoke_stub<...>)` will still always yield `R(*)(Args...)` -- which makes it really easy to store this internally so that it can be called back later.

(Note: this description is a little simplified -- usually the stub contains slightly more info to support member functions)

For a more in-depth breakdown of how this could be done, you can check out some tutorials I authored a few months ago that is coincidentally on exactly this topic: [Creating a fast and efficient delegate](https://bitwizeshift.github.io/posts/2021/02/24/creating-a-fast-and-efficient-delegate-type-part-1/). [Part 2](https://bitwizeshift.github.io/posts/2021/02/26/creating-a-fast-and-efficient-delegate-type-part-2/) discusses `auto` parameters, and [Part 3](https://bitwizeshift.github.io/posts/2021/02/26/creating-a-fast-and-efficient-delegate-type-part-3/) compares execution times with raw function pointers.

Comment: std::function can hold any type of callable, but the function signatures need to be the same between them, right?

Comment: _almost_. `std::function` actually allows for implicit conversions on arguments and output. You can have a `std::function<int(int)>` bind to a function of type `short(short)` and it just does the promotions for you. Similarly, `std::function<void(...)>` will discard the output if you bind a function that returns something. Using an `auto` non-type template parameter, you can basically write something that accomplishes the same thing -- only statically.